# C# - Stream a PDF using Response.TransmitFile() or Response.WriteFile() And then select a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, stream, response.write

I want to stream a pdf from a directory on the server using an ASP.NET page. This works fine. The catch is that I want to pass Adobe Open Parameters to land on a specific page.

Adobe has parameters for this: http://url/filename.pdf#page=XX

But, I can't find out how to stream the file rather than call it through a URL and get the #page= param to work.

Anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem, I was able to solve this issue. If you change the content disposition in the Response.AddHeader from attachment to inline, then setup your url as:

http://url/Downloader.aspx?fileid=XX#page=YY

This will work. Your aspx page will render the pdf in the browser and the page parameter will navigate to the appropriate page. Hope this helps!

Comment: FYI - This isn't just related to ASP.NET.  I had this same issue with Coldfusion and changing the header to inline worked.